# App engine index building stalled stuck

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, building, stalled

I am having a problem with indexes building in my App Engine application. There are only about 200 entities in the indexes that are being built, and the process has now been running for over 24 hours.

My application name is `romanceapp`.

Is there any way that I can re-start or clear the indexes that are being built?

Comment: You need to ask questions like this on the official groups - the only people who can help you are App Engine team members, and not many of us frequent Stack Overflow. Your indexes finished building on their own, however - a 24 hour wait time is not unusual, and the size of the index does not actually affect that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to redeploy your application to appspot, I have the same issue and this solved it.
Let me know if this helps.

Greeting, eng.Ilian Iliev

Answer (score 0):

> To handle "Error" indexes, first
>   remove them from your index.yaml file
>   and run appcfg.py vacuum_indexes.
>   Then, either reformulate the index
>   definition and corresponding queries
>   or remove the entities that are
>   causing the index to "explode."
>   Finally, add the index back to
>   index.yaml and run appcfg.py
>   update_indexes.

I found it [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html) and it helps me.